# .write() and .writelines() returning a blank .txt file -- PYTHON

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

I have three string, numpy arrays (all of the same length) containing all the information I need.

I am trying to put the arrays together in a meaningful way in an empty text file I have defined as '1RESULTS.txt'

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Code

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
temp_str = ' '
temp_bool = False

for (a, b, c) in zip(np_sub1, np_sub2, np_sub3):

    with open('1RESULTS.txt', 'w') as f:

        temp_bool = False

        if a != temp_str:

            f.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
            f.write('*****' + a + '*****')
            '\n'
            f.write(b + '--' + c + ';')

            temp_str = a
            temp_bool = True

        elif (temp_bool == False) and (a == temp_str):
            f.write(b + '--' + c + ';')
            '\n'

print('Type Unknown: ' + str(counter))
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

If I substitute 'f.write' with 'print' the output is as follows. This is what I would like 1RESULTS.txt to look like, but it remains blank.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*****42469000730000*****

17456638--Gamma;

2271876.--Resistivity;

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*****42469000840000*****

4881574.--Resistivity;

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

*****42469000850000*****

4881576.--Resistivity;
```

Comment: You're missing `f.close()` inside of your `with` block.

Comment: @hoffee No that is not the problem. The `with` statement always closes the file.

Comment: @hoffee There's no need to explicitly call `f.close()` when `with` is used. The problem here is that `f` is opened and rewritten every iteration. And thus the content of the file is what's written in the last iteration, which is possibly empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('1RESULTS.txt', 'w') as f:
```

here is your problem, you file is written over and over again each iteration deleting the previous entries. You should rather append to the file with

```
with open('1RESULTS.txt', 'a') as f:
```

EDIT:
better use the code as follows instead of opening and closing a stream so many times

```
temp_str = ' '
temp_bool = False

with open('1RESULTS.txt', 'w') as f:

    for (a, b, c) in zip(np_sub1, np_sub2, np_sub3):

        temp_bool = False

        if a != temp_str:

            f.write('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
            f.write('*****' + a + '*****')
            '\n'
            f.write(b + '--' + c + ';')

            temp_str = a
            temp_bool = True

        elif (temp_bool == False) and (a == temp_str):
            f.write(b + '--' + c + ';')
            '\n'

    print('Type Unknown: ' + str(counter))
```

Comment: I have performed your suggestion and (@ducminh)'s below collectively. For some reason I am still getting a blank file...but my code is executing must faster now. Are there separate open() sub-methods exclusive to using 'a'?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far Ishan, however I am still left with a blank .txt file. Do you have any further suggestions for how to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Varmushu would you mind specifying the full path to the file, just in case

Answer (score 1):

`f` is opened and rewritten every iteration. Thus only the last iteration affects the content of the file. Change the 3rd and 4th lines to

```
with open('1RESULTS.txt', 'w') as f:
    (a, b, c) in zip(np_sub1, np_sub2, np_sub3):
       ...
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: I have performed your suggestion and (@Ishan Srivastava)'s above collectively. For some reason I am still getting a blank file...but my code is executing must faster now. Are there any other obvious pitfalls to this code?

Answer (score 0):

The *with* statement manages the context of the *open* function, which processes the file for you.
You shouldn't put it inside the loop because it will create a new context for each object of the iteration.

Since you're opening the file in the 'w' mode, it will overwrite anything you wrote in the previous iteration.